# PHPUnit Mock Change the expectations later

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have a simple use case.  I want to have a setUp method which will cause my mock object to return a default value:

```
$this->myservice
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('checkUniqueness')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

But then in **some** tests, I want to return a different value:

```
$this->myservice
        ->expects($this->exactly(1))
        ->method('checkUniqueness')
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));
```

I've used GoogleMock for C++ in the past and it had "returnByDefault" or something to handle that.  I couldn't figure out if this is possible in PHPUnit (there is no api documentation and the code is difficult to read through to find what I want).

Now I can't just change `$this->myservice` to a new mock, because in setup, I pass it into other things that need to be mocked or tested.

My only other solution is that I lose the benefit of the setup and instead have to build up all of my mocks for every test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move the `setUp()` code into another method, which has parameters. This method gets then called from `setUp()`, and you may call it also from your test method, but with parameters different to the default ones.

Comment: How can this solve the issue? The `setUp()` method would be called anyway

Comment: @MassimilianoArione yes but you can re-create your `$this->myservice` and change the return value

Answer (score 1):

Continue building the mock in `setUp()` but set the expectation separately in each test:

```
class FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  private $myservice;
  private $foo;
  public function setUp(){
    $this->myService = $this->getMockBuilder('myservice')->getMock();
    $this->foo = new Foo($this->myService);
  }


  public function testUniqueThing(){
     $this->myservice
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('checkUniqueness')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

     $this->assertEqual('baz', $this->foo->calculateTheThing());
  }

  public function testNonUniqueThing(){
     $this->myservice
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('checkUniqueness')
        ->will($this->returnValue(false));

     $this->assertEqual('bar', $this->foo->calculateTheThing());

  }


}
```

The two expectations will not interfere with each other because PHPUnit instantiates a new instance of FooTest to run each test.

Answer (score 0):

Another little trick is to pass the variable by reference. That way you can manipulate the value:

```
public function callApi(string $endpoint):bool
{
    // some logic ...
}

public function getCurlInfo():array 
{
    // returns curl info about the last request
}
```

The above code has 2 public methods: `callApi()` that calls the API, and a second `getCurlInfo()`-method that provides information about the last request that's been done. We can mock the output of `getCurlInfo()` according to the arguments provided / mocked for `callApi()` by passing a variable as reference:

```
$mockedHttpCode = 0;
$this->mockedApi
    ->method('callApi')
    ->will(
        // pass variable by reference:
        $this->returnCallback(function () use (&$mockedHttpCode) {
            $args = func_get_args();
            $maps = [
                ['endpoint/x', true, 200],
                ['endpoint/y', false, 404],
                ['endpoint/z', false, 403],
            ];
            foreach ($maps as $map) {
                if ($args == array_slice($map, 0, count($args))) {
                    // change variable:
                    $mockedHttpCode = $map[count($args) + 1];
                    return $map[count($args)];
                }
            }
            return [];
        })
    );

$this->mockedApi
    ->method('getCurlInfo')
    // pass variable by reference:
    ->willReturn(['http_code' => &$mockedHttpCode]);
```

If you look closely, the `returnCallback()`-logic actually does the same thing as `returnValueMap()`, only in our case we can add a 3rd argument: the expected response code from the server.